# Simple wireless power transfer circuit question

Tags: power, power-electronics, three-phase, electromagnetic, wireless-charging

[image]

source: https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/simple-wireless-power-transmission-circuit-diagram

Above circuit is the very simple wireless power transfer circuit, but I could not find any explanation online about how the circuit actually works. How does the circuit on the left work as an oscillator? What is the purpose of the center tap, and how does it convert DC source into an oscillating current? Please help understand the circuit operation!

Also, how could this circuit be extended to a three phase one?

Comment: Precisely what do you mean by 3 phase? The present circuit runs from a 1.5 volt battery and is pretty low quality and inefficient. If you might be thinking about powering from 3 phase then you will need a fire extinguisher handy.

Comment: The link you posted explains it. Read the entire page.

Comment: @David What I'm looking for is a more detailed explanation. Of course I read the entire page.

Comment: I don't think that circuit works as the article describes either. Like you said, I don't understand how that circuit would oscillate.

Comment: FYI, I found out that this circuit configuration is called Joule Thief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work just fine (with some guessed values):

[image: test]

Note the polarity of the inductances. When power is turned on, there's no current through `L1`, but there is through `L2+R2` due to the BE junction being directly polarized. The transistor opens and allows current to flow through `L1`. When the transistor is saturated, there is no more variation in the current, so the induced `L1` is now transferring back to `L2`, and the cycle continues. Since the transistor can work with relatively high `dI/dt`, the values of the voltage can get very high, so some protection might be needed (or limit `dI/dt`). This schematic is a simple way of having a self-oscillating circuit.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Comment: @user207787 You should know two things: 1) the NPN needs an anti-parallel diode, to avoid damaging the transistor during reverse operation, and 2) as noted in the comments and in my conclusion, this circuit is very crude and inefficient; at best it has an educational value, to prove a concept, rather than to prove the schematic works. If you intend to use it, choose another. Not lastly, if any of the answers solve your problem, mark one of them (the check mark) so that future searches will show an accepted answer for this question.

Comment: Done!
Also, I was asked to extend this to a three phase one, and I have no idea what that means. Can you give me some suggestion?

Comment: @user207787 That makes no sense to me. Can't you ask for clarifications from whomever asked you this in ther first place? Was it your teacher? It would great if you could add that clarification to your question, I am always glad to learn something new.

Comment: I didn't get that " induced L1 is now transferring back to L2" part. Would you help me?

Comment: @Giga-Byte Yes, that came out weird. I meant that, since `L1` and `L2` are in anti-phase, they behave like a transformer, so the induced voltage appears in `L2` after the cycle in `L1` finishes -- when the transistor is saturated there is no more variation in the current through `L1`. Did my translating neuron made it this time?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I asked him and apparently I need three BJTs and three center taps on the left side of the circuit. I don't know if that will create voltages 120 degrees apart, but I guess I will try.

Comment: @user207787 Ask him the *purpose* of havng a three-phase wireless transmitter, particularly since the power transmitted is in the order of mW. If you think you can use that to power a 1 HP motor, you're day-dreaming. You're lucky if you can power your cell-phone with WPT. The notion of three-phase WPT is simply ludicrous.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the coil wounds are same, each with 17 turns.
So the induced EMF is neither decreasing nor increasing but I don't think it's possible for it to convert DC as low as 1.5V into an oscillating current.

Comment: The number of turns is not the key here, it's the polarity of the inductances, an effect of the center tap, which causes the two inductances to work alternatively, and which makes the whole circuit a self-oscillating one. I may have exaggerated with the coupling factor in my answer, but it works, even at k=0.3, even at 1.5 V.