# How does only transistor and inductior without a capacitor oscillator work

Tags: transistors, oscillator

It has been more than 10 years, I left electronics. I saw this circuit of wireless power transfer, it has to do with induction, but the oscillator circuit shown doesn't contain a capacitor. can anyone explain to me how this will work?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a blocking oscillator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_oscillator)...

Comment: Self-capacitance probably.

Comment: It's a typical "joule thief" design *with an added secondary.* I think I've described how that works more than once here, but [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/504640/38098) is the more recent attempt. However, I'm not sure in this case about coil's reversal and the impact on the BJT.

Comment: This question has been asked before: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519662/simple-wireless-power-transfer-circuit-question

Comment: *doesn't contain a capacitor* There is **ALWAYS** some capacitance present, for example the junctions of the NPN have a small capacitance between them. But this circuit doesn't need any capacitance to resonate.

Comment: Exactly, initially, I thought the transistor is a MOSFET, as MOSFET has higher C but I looked closely to find it to be a BJT.I got it from the link shared by @LarsHankeln